# No usb devices or running emulators detected

Tags: android, usb

I tried running my first `Hello World` app in android studio in my samsung phone, but I got this message even though the phone was connected through usb:

```
no usb devices or running emulators detected
```

> note: usb debugging is enabled in my phone

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: whats use of xml here? Is there any relation of xml and your question?

Comment: Improved grammar, removed xml layout.

Comment: I'd recommend you verifying that the proper USB drivers are installed if you are using a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this problem by the following:

1-make sure the oem driver for samsung (SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones) is installed

2-if you have another usb port,try to disconnect your phone,and reconnect in another usb port

the second solution solved this problem well>>>>>

Answer (score 1):

Connecting your device for development. (Preferred and Fast developing option)

1. Open your phone's setting->developer options and turn on USB debugging. Then connect your device.
2. Download Google Usb Driver from SDK Manager. Install your device's required drivers on your computer. And connect.

Using emulator(slow process)

1. Create new android virtual device(AVD) and download required sdk versions.
2. Run your app on AVD.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

install the Samsung kies3 and it will work

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after upgrading Android.  I am running a Google Pixel phone.  When I did the upgrade, the USB Configuration setting on my phone, apparently, changed from MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) to Charging.  I changed it back to MTP and it works now.  I upgraded from Android 7.1.1 to 7.1.2.